# Android ProgressDialog- Unable to Add Window. is Your Activity is Running

Tags: android, progressdialog

When I place a ProgressDialog in **AsyncTask onPreExecute()** it shows:

> Unable add window, is your activity running?

Here is my Code

```
  ProgressDialog pDialog=new ProgressDialog(getParent());
//ProgressDialog pDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
  pDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass to `ProgressDialog` constructor current `Activity` instance

```
new ProgressDialog(activity)
```

Comment: you mean MainActivity.this